# Wordpress Category Permalinks

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting, permalinks

My category permalinks are currently set up like:

http://carladessi.com/category/portfolio/

http://carladessi.com/portfolio/example-post

but I want to remove the /category/ so it's:

http://carladessi.com/portfolio/

http://carladessi.com/portfolio/example-post

Comment: Agree with Greg L, search Stackoverflow first before asking questions.

Answer (score 0):

In permalink setting u can change like this

/%category%/%postname%/

To this:

/%postname%/